# Ordering default case in PHP switch statements

Tags: php, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [default as first option in switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241695/default-as-first-option-in-switch-statement)

In all tutorials I've seen, `default:` is the last option in a switch/case statement.

However, I have a situation where the `default:` behavior will be by far the most common. For readability I'd like to describe the `default:` behavior first, then the edge cases below.

Will this work, or am I going to cause the `default:` statement to always be that one that's evaluated (on some or all systems)?

Comment: It would take you less time to test this in a tiny script than it would to post the question!

Comment: @jcmeloni: I meant in my particular use. Generally when I use "switch" it's the opposite: "default" is the least common.

Comment: @amindfv fair enough; just wanted to get the info on the record for anyone happening across this question in the future.

Comment: @jcmeloni: Edited for clarity.

Comment: @John3136: that's a fair point, but it would only demonstrate what happens on my php install, and I want to know how it will work in general.

Comment: This is *not* an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241695/default-as-first-option-in-switch-statement. That deals with the more-complex behavior of matching the default case and then falling through to other case matching.

Answer (score 4):

It will work.  You just want to make sure that you conclude the block following the default with a break line.  Here is an example:

```
<?php
$action = $_GET['action'];

switch ($action)
{
  default:
  {
    echo "default case";
    break;
  }

  case "hello":
  {
    echo "hello world";
    break;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Braces on cases statements ?! Weird...

Comment: @FMaz008 The braces aren't necessary, but I've gotten in the habit of using them as they are friendly to code folding editors.

Comment: @DuaneGran w00t. I agree on the braces ^_^

Comment: So are we agreeing that this is correct, and @thisisablock's answer isn't?

Comment: @amindfv Well, I certainly I am.  :)  The php.net docs also show cases where the order doesn't matter so I think we can put this one to rest.