# Check for file extension JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some handy code which checks the file extension of a file for me and attaches an image depending on the result.

If the extension doesn't match any of the ones I have listed, I want to attach a generic 'Unknown' image. What could I enter into the case to accomplish this?

```
    function get_extension(file_name) {
        return file_name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    }

    function check_file_type(file) { 
        switch(get_extension(file)) {
            //if .jpg/.gif/.png do something
            case 'jpg': case 'gif': case 'png':
                return '{!URLFOR($Resource.Common, 'images/filetypes/doctype_image.png')}';
                break;
            //if .zip/.rar do something else
            case 'zip': case 'rar':
                return '{!URLFOR($Resource.Common, 'images/filetypes/doctype_zip.png')}';
                break;      
            //if .pdf do something else
            case 'pdf': case 'pptx':
                return '{!URLFOR($Resource.Common, 'images/filetypes/doctype_pdf.png')}';
                break;
            //if .docx do something else
            case 'docx':
                return '{!URLFOR($Resource.Common, 'images/filetypes/doctype_word.png')}';
                break;
            //if unknown do something else
            case 'WHAT DO I DO HERE' <-- ???
                return '{!URLFOR($Resource.Common, 'images/filetypes/doctype_other.png')}';
                break;
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: there is a `default` for case statements:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `default:`

```
    switch(get_extension(file)) {
        //if .jpg/.gif/.png do something
        case 'jpg': case 'gif': case 'png':
            return '{!URLFOR($Resource.Common, 'images/filetypes/doctype_image.png')}';
            break;
        //if .zip/.rar do something else
        case 'zip': case 'rar':
            return '{!URLFOR($Resource.Common, 'images/filetypes/doctype_zip.png')}';
            break;      
        //if .pdf do something else
        case 'pdf': case 'pptx':
            return '{!URLFOR($Resource.Common, 'images/filetypes/doctype_pdf.png')}';
            break;
        //if .docx do something else
        case 'docx':
            return '{!URLFOR($Resource.Common, 'images/filetypes/doctype_word.png')}';
            break;
        //if unknown do something else
        default:
            return '{!URLFOR($Resource.Common, 'images/filetypes/doctype_other.png')}';
            break;
    }
```

Comment: No need to use `break` in the `default` case. **Quote:** _"The optional break statement associated with each case label ensures that the program breaks out of switch once the matched statement is executed and continues execution at the statement following switch. If break is omitted, the program continues execution at the next statement in the switch statement."_ from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: @maxpower9000 I tend to use it in all cases just for consistency.

Comment: To be pedantic, the place where `break` is unnecessary is the last case, which isn't necessarily the `default` case. You might not have a `default`, and `default` doesn't have to be last: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241695/default-as-first-option-in-switch-statement

Comment: **True** Exactly what the MDN quote in my comment states. The comment comments the acual code above, it’s not a comment on javascipt itself, in _this case_ one could have omitted the `break` in the `default` case. The codes awesome still, cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You wouldn't use a case if nothing matches, you would use default. It would look like:

```
function get_extension(file_name) {
    return file_name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
}

function check_file_type(file) { 
    switch(get_extension(file)) {
        //if .jpg/.gif/.png do something
        case 'jpg': case 'gif': case 'png':
            return '{!URLFOR($Resource.Common, 'images/filetypes/doctype_image.png')}';
            break;
        //if .zip/.rar do something else
        case 'zip': case 'rar':
            return '{!URLFOR($Resource.Common, 'images/filetypes/doctype_zip.png')}';
            break;      
        //if .pdf do something else
        case 'pdf': case 'pptx':
            return '{!URLFOR($Resource.Common, 'images/filetypes/doctype_pdf.png')}';
            break;
        //if .docx do something else
        case 'docx':
            return '{!URLFOR($Resource.Common, 'images/filetypes/doctype_word.png')}';
            break;
        //if unknown do something else
        default:
            return '{!URLFOR($Resource.Common, 'images/filetypes/doctype_other.png')}';
            break;
    }
}
```